# Load only particular field in PIG?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, apache-pig

This is my file:

`Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5`

I need only `Col2` and `Col3`.

Currently I'm doing this:

```
a = load 'input' as (Col1:chararray, 
                     Col2:chararray, 
                     Col3:chararray, 
                     Col4:chararray);
b = foreach a generate Col2, Col3;
```

Is there a way to do directly load only `Col2` and `Col3` instead of loading the whole `input` and then `generate` required columns?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your method of only `GENERATE`ing the columns you want is an effective way to do just what you ask. Remember that all of your data is stored on HDFS, and you're not loading it all into memory when you start your script. You still will have to read those bytes off the disk even if you are not keeping them around for use in your processing, so there is no performance advantage to never loading that data.  The advantage comes in never having to send it to a reducer, which you have accomplished with your method.

In cases where Pig can tell that a column won't be used, it will "prune" it immediately, essentially doing for you what you did with your `b = foreach a generate Col2, Col3;`. This won't happen, however, if you are using a UDF that might access other fields, because Pig doesn't look inside the UDF to see if they get used. For example, suppose `Col3` is an `int`.  If you have

```
b = group a by Col2;
c = foreach b generate group, SUM(a.Col3);
```

then Pig will automatically prune the 1st and 4th columns for you, since it can see they're never used.  However, if you instead did

```
b = group a by Col2;
c = foreach b generate group, COUNT(a);
```

then Pig can't prune, because it doesn't see inside the `COUNT` UDF and doesn't know that the other fields won't be used. When in doubt of whether Pig will do this pruning, you can use the `foreach`/`generate` method you already have. And Pig should print a diagnostic message when you start your script listing all the columns it was able to prune out.

If instead your problem is that you don't want to have to provide a full schema when you're interested in just a few columns, you can skip the schema entirely and put it in the `GENERATE`:

```
a = load 'input';
b = foreach a generate (chararray) $1 as Col2, (chararray) $2 as Col3;
```

Comment: In my case (Apache Pig 0.17.0), `a = load 'input' using PigStorage(',');` gave correct output. I think if we don't use PigStorage(), then Pig considers entire line as a tuple of type `chararray`.

Comment: @novato, the default delimiter for PigStorage is `\t`. If you have comma-separated data, then it will see it as one long `chararray` because there were no delimiters found.