# Is there any way toread only required columns from CSV in Pig?

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig, cloudera

I have a CSV file with about 50 columns in it. I want to read only particular columns from it. Is there any way I can do that?

Example:

> CSV has, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6,......,col50

I want load

```
load 'path to file' as (col1, col18, col47);
```

I want to do something like that.

Comment: Duplicate [load-only-particular-field-in-pig](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20858990/load-only-particular-field-in-pig)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load it than project it:

```
REGISTER 'piggybank.jar'
DEFINE CSVLoader org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader();
A = LOAD 'data.csv' USING CSVLoader();
B = FOREACH A GENERATE 
    $0 AS col1,
    $17 AS col18,
    $46 AS col47;
...
```